# Caption property not working for gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, pdf-generation, caption

I was trying to export pdf file from database in asp.net. Here, I followed this link: http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-DataSet-or-DataTable-to-Word-Excel-PDF-and-CSV-Formats.aspx

**For Export .doc file:**

```
string strQuery = "select CustomerID, ContactName, City, PostalCode" +
                      " from customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    //Create a dummy GridView
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=DataTable.doc");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word ";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    GridView1.Caption = "<br><br><br>" + "<h3>" + "Register Users Table" + "</h3>" + "<br>";
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Here Caption was displayed the top of the GridView in the .doc file

**For Export .pdf file:**

```
string strQuery = "select CustomerID, ContactName, City, PostalCode" +
        " from customers";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    //Create a dummy GridView
    GridView GridView1 = new GridView();
    GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
        "attachment;filename=DataTable.pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    GridView1.Caption = "<br><br><br>" + "<h3>" + "Register Users Table" + "</h3>" + "<br>";
    StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
    HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDoc.Open();
    htmlparser.Parse(sr);
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
```

Here the Caption of the GridView not displayed... How to display the caption of the Gridview  in  Exporting the pdf file in C# asp.net

How to do this.. Is there any wrong in my code??
Thanks in advance..